# Early 2018 gas price volatility

Tags: gas, gas-price

What have caused the recent default gas price

- To go up (default was in some point near 100 GWei)
- To come down (now it seems to be 20 GWei)

Specifically, was this because of

- Actual demand for Ethereum transactions
- Gas oracles, other gas price estimation mechanisms

Comment: IMO the main cause were gas wars during big ICO sales and projects like Cryptokitties which skyrocketed demand for transactions. And the price growth ofc.